# If $\langle a\rangle$ is a cyclic group of order $90$, write $a$ as the product of $p$-elements, for various primes $p$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, cyclic-groups

We say that $a$ is a $p$-element if the order of $a$ is $p^n$ for some integer $n\ge0$.
The primes dividing $p$ are $2,3$ and $5$.

Thus the $2$ - elements are $\{e,a^{45}\}$.

The $3$ - elements are $\{e,a^{10},a^{20},a^{30},a^{40},a^{50},a^{60},a^{70},a^{80},a^{90}\}$.

The $5$ - elements are $\{e,a^{18},a^{36},a^{54},a^{72}\}$

---

How can I write $a$ as product of these?

Comment: The correct way to write the exponent is like this $a^{45}$

Comment: Throw some {} around the exponents to get both numbers to be raised as @kabenyuk has done.

Comment: If you write `a^45` you get $a^45$. To get $a^{45}$ you need to write `a^{45}`.

Comment: And the other degrees still look terrible.

Comment: The lists are not correct.

Comment: Now I have corrected the list . So a = $a^{10}a^{45}a^{36}$ ? @IgorRivin

Comment: $a^{90}=e $.  Your sylow-3 subgroup should have order $9$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $a^{36},a^{10} $ and $a^{45} $ have orders $5,9$ and  $2$, respectively,  you can take their product.